# Select2 doesn't trigger on change/selection of first option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, select2-rails

What I am doing: Dynamically adding options to a select box when modal popup opens. And waiting for `on change` trigger to respond.

**Observation**: It pops up alert box for all options but first.
Below is the code.

```
$("#query_product").on("change", function(e){
  alert(1)
});

$("#add_condition_modal").on( "shown.bs.modal", function() {
  options = ['<option>one</option>','<option>two</option>','<option>three</option>']
  $('#query_product').find('option').remove()
  $('#query_product').append(options); 
});

<select id="query_product" name="query_product" required></select>
```

**Another Observation**: When I prefill the html select box with same options and then select the first option or any option, I see the alert popup.
Now I am confused.

I tried using event delegation for dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on("change","#query_product", function() {
```

Nothing seems to work. Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#query_product").on("change", function(e){
  alert(1)
});

$("#add_condition_modal").on( "shown.bs.modal", function() {
  options = ['<option value="one">one</option>','<option value="two">two</option>','<option value="three">three</option>']
  $('#query_product').find('option').remove();
  $('#query_product').append(options); 
  $('#query_product').val("");
});

<select id="query_product" name="query_product" required></select>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But can you explain why was it needed to set empty val to select box. I would really like to know

Comment: That was to reset the value of the select box, so that a change event can be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Here's you're doing it bit wrong.

`['<option>one</option>','<option>two</option>','<option>three</option>']`
I'd suggest use string.

```
$("#query_product").on("change", function(e){
  alert(1)
});

$("#add_condition_modal").on( "shown.bs.modal", function() {
  options ='<option>one</option><option>two</option><option>three</option>';
  $('#query_product').html(options);
});

<select id="query_product" name="query_product" required></select>
```

When you're using `remove()` jQuery function it removes the select2 as well.
so reinitializing would be fix for you.

**Note**: If you want to use array of options then do it like this.

```
var options = ['first_option','second_option','third_option'];
var optionString = '';
    for(var i = 0; i< options.length; i++){
        optionString += '<option>'+options[i]+'</option>';
    }
 then $('#selector').html(optionString);
```

Here's a Fiddle that might help
https://jsfiddle.net/imrealashu/61tvh76t/3/

Comment: Nope, commented out `$('#query_product').find('option').remove()` .. still same results

Comment: did you try to reinitialize it ? `$('#query_product').append(options).select2();` instead of removing  `$('#query_product').find('option').remove()` ?

Comment: let me create a fiddle for you.

Comment: Tried that now. Same results :|

Comment: I've updated the answer as well as fiddle link. Try that It will work.

Comment: Fiddle does work, however only after I choose any other option but first, and then i choose first option. It should work the very first time. The same has been happening with me

Comment: Trudeau Fenanades's answer above works in both cases.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that answer too. That worked for me. even mine answer worked.